# How can I run a ROS service when my app starts?

Tags: c#, ros

I have a C# application and I need to add a record and play function for the bag files. I was done creating the service client for these two functions. I can get the list of bag files on my local directory and was also able to play a selected bag file as well. However, I need to manually start the service on a terminal, because without doing so, I get an error that my service "/bag_server" is not available at ROS master.

*running service for bag List:*

```
ubuntu@test:~/rosbag/src$ rosrun service_pkg baglist.py
[INFO] [WallTime: 1570761469.491990] rosbag list provider started...
```

*running service for rosbag playback*

```
ubuntu@test:~/rosbag/src$ rosrun service_pkg baglist.py
[INFO] [WallTime: 1570761469.491990] rosbag playback started...
```

We also had an sdk where ROS is configured. I am quite thinking of adding a configuration on sdk but I am unsure where to start to. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to start two nodes at once? Have a look at [launch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) files then.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time to leave a comment. I actually haven't considered this before but was also realized that I also needed this one. Thanks for noticing it, and I am working on it now. This is really helpful. I haven't thought of running these services at once. Kudos!